# Мультиязычный сайт на Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, multilanguage

Тариф на хостинге не дает возможность создать отдельную базу данных для каждой версии сайта.
Использую ACF. WP Multilang не помог.
Вот к примеру страница сайта [karvan](http://karvan/ux-ui-design/)

В сайдбаре выводятся названия фильтров через ACF. Через WP Multilang не получилось. При переключении языков названия фильтров не менялись.
Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из бесплатных Polylang. Он создает разные страницы и посты для разных языков, просто связывает их между собой. Для каких то общих данных есть список переводов в который можно добавить свои слова и переводы. Из платных WPML.